# The details about space probes and everything thats on-board and what controls them/tells them what to do?

Tags: probe, electronics

I just was really curious about all the different electronics and everything that has to do with space probes and I couldn't find just one site telling me everything I wanted to know so if someone could give me a detailed explanation about all the systems that make them fly I'm just really curious. Thanks.

--------edit---------

I'm also considering exploring the felid of commercial space flight so really any info helps. Again thanks.

Comment: This question is *very* broad at the moment and a detailed answer would likely be hundreds of pages long. If you could narrow your question to a particular aspect of  probe control, that would be great!

Answer (score 2):

How I do search information about a spacecraft:

1. Chooze the spacecraft you like (for example New Horizons).
2. Go to its [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Horizons)
3. If wiki info is not enough, look for reference links on the page
4. If you still didn't find - Google it (search "new horizons spacecraft" for clarity)
5. For more bulky information add to the search word "pdf"

---

For "new horizons spacecraft electronics pdf" I found this, for example:
http://www.boulder.swri.edu/pkb/ssr/ssr-fountain.pdf

The doc contains basic info about design of the spacecraft.

Is it like something you are looking for?

P.S. It works with most USA (not-classified) and European spacecraft. For Indian and Japanese can work too. For Russian spacecraft you can find mission overwiev, but technical details are usually scarce, as well as for Chinese crafts.